# django memcached setting location list has tuples?

Tags: django, memcached, setting

Just saw this configuration in one of the project setting.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'KEY_PREFIX' : 'projectabc:',
        'LOCATION': [
                ('10.1.1.1:11211', 1),
                ('10.1.1.2:11211', 1),
                ('10.1.1.3:11211', 1),
                ('10.1.1.4:11211', 1),
        ],
    }
}
```

Just curious why have tuples inside `LOCATION`? what's the "1" in the tuple for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in python-memcached, `location` ultimately gets sent to this function. It seems its a redundant (but helpful reminder) that a weight param exists.

```
def set_servers(self, servers):
    """
    Set the pool of servers used by this client.

    @param servers: an array of servers.
    Servers can be passed in two forms:
        1. Strings of the form C{"host:port"}, which implies a default weight of 1.
        2. Tuples of the form C{("host:port", weight)}, where C{weight} is
        an integer weight value.
    """
```